# SQL searching value when all the inputs are matched and there's no different term than the ones searched

Tags: sql

I have this database:

```
Id          TsOffersId  OffersId
----------- ----------- -----------
0           0           0
1           0           9
2           0           16
3           1           0
4           1           9
5           1           16
6           1           20
7           2           0
8           2           9
```

I get from the input some values for the "OffersId", let's say I get 0, 9, and 16.

In this case I need to match only the rows with a TsOffersId value of 0, because:

- TsOffersId = 1 is in a row with an OffersId value different than 0, 9, and 16
- TsOffersId = 2 isn't in any row  with an OffersId = 16

Any elegant solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with aggregation and a `having` clause.  Here is one way:

```
select TsOffersId
from databasetable t
group by TsOffersId
having count(distinct OffersId) = 3 and
       count(distinct case when OffersId in (0, 9, 16) then OffersId end) = 3;
```

The first condition checks that there are three distinct values (so there are no extras).  The second checks that there are three distinct values when you only look at specific values (so all values are there).